# Error while implementing CanDeactivate Guard

Tags: angular, angular-guards, angular-httpclient-interceptors

I'm currently trying to implement a CanDeactivate Guard to my angular application which already had HTTP Interceptor to resolve for authentication. 
But adding the CanDeactivate guard is throwing Error as mentioned below.

I have registered the Class which implements the CanDeactivate interface in providers array of the AppModule.
I have registered the class which implements the CanDeactivate interface in the canDeactivate property of the route.

class implementing the CanDeactivate Interface :

```js
export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
  canComponentDeactivate(): boolean;
}

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AppRegisterDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<AppRegisterComponent> {
  canDeactivate(
    component: AppRegisterComponent,
    currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    currentState: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean {
    return component.isDeactivated;
  }
}
```

Component in which the Deactivate guard is applied :

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-app-register',
  templateUrl: './app-register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-register.component.css']
})
export class AppRegisterComponent implements OnInit, CanComponentDeactivate {
  isDeactivated = false;
  @ViewChild('registrationForm') registForm: NgForm;
.
.
canComponentDeactivate() {
    if (this.registForm.dirty) {
      this.isDeactivated = confirm('You have modified changes in the form. \nDo you still want to navigate away ? ');
    }
    return this.isDeactivated;
  }
}
```

Route definition for that endpoint :

```js
...
{ path: 'register', component: AppRegisterComponent, canDeactivate: ['AppRegisterDeactivateGuard'] },
```

Providers array in the Module :

```js
 providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: AppAuthInterceptService,
    multi: true
  }, AppRegisterDeactivateGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

ERROR

```
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppRegisterDeactivateGuard]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for AppRegisterDeactivateGuard!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppRegisterDeactivateGuard]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppRegisterDeactivateGuard]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for AppRegisterDeactivateGuard!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:8896)
    at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:8982)
    at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:8982)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:21218)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:21907)
    at getToken (router.js:2865)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:502)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1744)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR;
Change your route to this:

```
{ path: 'register', component: AppRegisterComponent, canDeactivate: [AppRegisterDeactivateGuard] }
```

Change your providers to this:

```
[{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: AppAuthInterceptService,
    multi: true
  }]
```

Longer answer:

AppRegisterDeactivateGuard having both `{providedIn: 'root'}` and declaring it as a provider in the module is unnecessary. [See the Angular provider docs](https://angular.io/guide/providers).

The issue here is a combination with the route and providers.

Right now your route is looking for a token via the string name, however it is available via the class name.

Using `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})` how you have it uses the class name as the token, and it will be available as AppRegisterDeactivateGuard.

Having `AppRegisterDeactivateGuard` in your providers how you have it *also* will make it available as AppRegisterDeactivateGuard.

I don't recommend this, but if you want or need to reference it via string names, you can put it in the providers like so:

```
{ provide: 'AppRegisterDeactivateGuard', useClass: AppRegisterDeactivateGuard }
```

Comment: Thanks @OneLunchMan. 
It was silly mistake to have the class registered as a string in route definition. Changing it to the class name solved it. I know that registering the service both with the meta-data and providers array is unnecessary, but I did that while debugging just to make sure that it gets registered. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the interface in generics :

```
export class AppRegisterDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate > {
```

and then implement canDeactivate method